# Выдает наши при генерации случайных уникальных чисел

Tags: c++

```
            #include <iostream>
            #include <ctime>
            using namespace std;





                int main()
                {
                    srand(time(NULL));
                    const int SIZE=10;
                int randArray[SIZE]={-1};
                    int random;
                    int table[SIZE];
                    bool exists;
            for (int i=0;i<=SIZE;)
            {random=rand();



                    for(int j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
                {if (table[j]==random)
                    {
                        exists=true;
                    }}
                        if(exists==false)
                    {   randArray[i]=random;
                    i++;
                    }
                    cout<<randArray[i]<<"\n";
                }


            return 0;
            }
```

Comment: Что-что выдаёт??? В чём вопрос?

Comment: Вот смысл оформлять это и подобное как `C++` код? ради того чтоб в конце использовать `cout` вместо `printf` ? чистый `C` одним словом, с ужасным форматированием.

Comment: Бросается в глаза обращение `randArray[i]` за пределами массива. Кроме того, непонятно зачем печатать значение незаполненного (следующего) элемента.

Answer (score 2):

У меня ощущение, что вы хотите [вот это](https://ideone.com/Xl2aSo):

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    const int SIZE=10;

    int randArray[SIZE];

    int random;
    int table[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        for(bool exists;; )
        {
            exists = false;
            random = rand();
            for(int j = 0; j<i; j++)
            {
                if (table[j] == random)
                {
                    exists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!exists) break;
        }
        cout << (randArray[i]=random) << endl;
    }
}
```